# Custom annotation for User roles for Spring Security

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-security, enums, roles

I'd like to make annotation that control access controller method. Firstly, I have enum class for roles that property for ModelUser Class:

```
enum class ModelUserRole : GrantedAuthority {
    REGULAR,
    COMPANY_ADMIN,
    SUPER_ADMIN;

    override fun getAuthority(): String? {
        return name
    }
}
```

and custom annotation:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole(T(project.com.example.data.ModelUserRole).COMPANY_ADMIN)")
annotation class CompanyAdmin()
```

However, when I add this annotation to my controller class like this:

```
@GetMapping
@CompanyAdmin
fun getUsersByCompanyAdmin( request: HttpServletRequest): Collection<UserAccount> {
       // logic

    }
```

it doesn't change anything. User with any role can user this method. What am I missing?